# Nested DIV tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 DIVs one inside the other.I want to toggle between alert texts.The condition is when the region between inner and outer div is selected,outer divs alert must come else inner divs alert must come.How can i proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop the `event propagation` of inner `div` by using `stopPropagation()`, Try this:

HTML

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#outer {
    background: green;
    padding: 20px;
}
#inner {
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#outer').click(function() {
        alert('outer div alert');
    });
    $('#inner').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('inner div alert');
    });
});
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/XNZ29/)**